# Decorating top function in MRO

Tags: python, inheritance, wrapper, python-decorators, metaclass

How can I decorate the last function in a class inheritance?

If I decorate a superclass function, the subclass function overrides the decorator.
I'd like to find out if there is a neat way to automatically decorate the top function in the MRO.

```
def wrapper(f):
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print("In wrapper")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrap


class A:

    @wrapper
    def f(self):
        print("In class A")


class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("In class B")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print("Calling A:")
    a.f()
    print("Calling B:")
    b.f()
```

Here is the output. As expected, B.f() does not call the wrapper, though I'd like it to.

```
Calling A:
In wrapper
In class A

Calling B:
In class B
```

Here is what I have tried thus far. A metaclass that holds all the decorators and injects them during class instantiation.

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class WrapperMetaClass(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        wrappers_dict = getattr(cls, "_wrappers")
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            if attr_name not in wrappers_dict:
                continue
            else:
                wrapper = wrappers_dict[attr_name]
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if not hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
                raise Exception("What you're trying to wrap is not a function!")
            attr = wrapper(attr)
            setattr(cls, attr_name, attr)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works:

```
class A(metaclass=WrapperMetaClass):
    _wrappers = {
        "f": wrapper
    }

    def f(self):
        print("In class A")


class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("In class B")
```

The output is what I wanted.

```
Calling A:
In wrapper
In class A

Calling B:
In wrapper
In class B
```

However, this runs into a different issue. If B does not override f, the metaclass wraps A.f() twice. This makes sense, as both A and B inherit WrapperMetaClass, so A.f() is wrapped first, and then B.f() is wrapped again.

```
class A(metaclass=WrapperMetaClass):
    _wrappers = {
        "f": wrapper
    }

    def f(self):
        print("In class A")


class B(A):
    pass
```

The output becomes:

```
Calling A:
In wrapper
In class A

Calling B:
In wrapper
In wrapper
In class A
```

I have no idea what else I could do.

Comment: If `B.f` calls `A.f`, do you want it to behave like `A.f` is wrapped, or like `A.f` is not wrapped?

Comment: `for attr_name in dir(cls):` If you want to iterate over class attributes and modify them, why not to use [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)?

Comment: I'd like only B.f to be wrapped.
Think of use case where decorator adds threadsafe functionality, i.e. a lock. I'd like B.f to use the lock. It would not make sense for A.f to also use the lock.

Comment: @OlvinRoght this actually could work, I will try it.

Comment: @IvanTsenov, this is actually how it should work :D

Comment: Why not apply more simple logic and just call `super().f()` in the subclass and you will catch all the decorators from super classes?

Comment: The usual approach for what you're asking for is to have *two* methods. The first one contains the logic that would have gone in the wrapper, and it calls the second method. The *second* method is the one that subclasses override.

Comment: As for using a plain threading.Lock - it would work, but would ironically break the decorator in a multi-threading enviroment if the subclass wrapped method is actually called from concurrent threads. But it is a matter of refining the Lock's use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I remember facing this once or twice - and you are on the right track.

But first things first: if the logic in your "wrapper" is something that
could be put in a method in the base class, then breaking-up the methods
in smaller-tasks, and have a "method slot" system is preferable to this,
as [user 2357112 supports monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) puts in the comments. If you find out you really need or prefer decorators, the full code is bellow

```py
class A:
    def do_things(self):
        create_connection()  # <- this is the code you'd are putting in the wrapper in the other approach
        do_thing_1()

class B(A):
    def do_things(self):
        # here we have to do thing_1 and thing_2, but
        # the connection is created in the superclass method... 
        # this could be the origin of your question
        
# Refactor to:

class A:
    def do_things(self):
        create_connection()
        self.internal_do_things()
        
    def internal_do_things(self):
        do_thing_1()
        
class B(A):
    def internal_do_things(self):
        super().internal_do_things()
        do_thing_2()
```

So, classical inheritance and OO solves this

---

**If you need the decorators anway:**

The thing to do is to have the decorator itself, the "wrapper", get
a way to "know" if it already was called in an outer method (i.e. a method
in a subclass which calls `super()`), and just act as a transparent
wrapper in this case.

It gets a bit further complicated when we want a robust solution:
a wrapper that can work for different methods in the same class,
and does not get confused if they are called concurrently
(in different threads, or a method calling another method,
not `super()`, which should trigger the wrapper).

And in the end, the mechanisms for that are complicated enough that
they should not get in the way of your actual wrapper - so,
ideally they should be built as a decorator themselves, which will
decorate your wrapper.

[hours later]
So, sorry if it does not look "neat" - it turns out implementing what is described above is a bit more complex than I thought initially - we need an intermediate decorator level (called `meta_wrapper_applier` in the code), so that the metaclass can re-wrap the methods each time they are redeclared.

I hope the comments in the code and variable names are enough to understand the idea:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta
from functools import wraps
import threading


class WrapperMetaClass(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, ns, **kw):
        super().__init__(name, bases, ns, **kw)

        # Get the wrapped methods for all the superclasses
        super_wrappers = {}
        for supercls in cls.__mro__[::-1]:
            super_wrappers.update(supercls.__dict__.get("_wrappers", {}))

        # unconditionally install a wrappers dict for each subclass:
        sub_wrappers =  cls._wrappers = {}

        for attrname, attr in ns.items():
            if attrname in super_wrappers:
                # Applies the wrapper in the baseclass to the subclass method:
                setattr(cls, attrname, super_wrappers[attrname]._run_once_wrapper(attr))
            elif hasattr(attr, "_run_once_wrapper"):
                # Store the wrapper information in the cls for use of the subclasses:
                sub_wrappers[attrname] = attr


def run_once_method_decorator(original_wrapper):
    re_entering_stacks = {}

    # This is the callable used to place a wrapper on the original
    # method and on each overriden method.
    # All methods with the same name in the subclasses  will share the same original wrapper and the
    # "re_entering_stacks" data structure.
    def meta_wrapper_applier(raw_method):
        wrapped_method_in_subclass = None
        @wraps(original_wrapper)
        def meta_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            nonlocal wrapped_method_in_subclass

            # uses a plain list to keep track of re-entering the same-named method
            # in each thread:
            re_entering_stack = re_entering_stacks.setdefault(threading.current_thread(), [])
            re_entering = bool(re_entering_stack)
            try:
                re_entering_stack.append(1)
                if re_entering:
                    result = raw_method(*args, **kw)
                else:
                    if wrapped_method_in_subclass is None:
                        # Applies the original decorator lazily, and caches the result:
                        wrapped_method_in_subclass = original_wrapper(raw_method)

                    result = wrapped_method_in_subclass(*args, **kw)
            finally:
                re_entering_stack.pop()
            return result
        # registry = original_wrapper.__dict__.setdefault("_run_once_registry", {})


        meta_wrapper._run_once_wrapper = meta_wrapper_applier
        return meta_wrapper

    return meta_wrapper_applier

# From here on, example code only;

@run_once_method_decorator
def wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Entering wrapper")
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Leaving wrapper\n")
        return result
    return _wrap

@run_once_method_decorator
def other_wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Entering other wrapper")
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Leaving other wrapper\n")
        return result
    return _wrap


class A(metaclass=WrapperMetaClass):

    @wrapper
    def f(self):
        print("In class A")

    def g(self):
        print("g in A")

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("In class B")
        super().f()

    @other_wrapper
    def g(self):
        print("g in B")
        super().g()

class C(B):
    def g(self):
        print("g in C")
        super().g()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print("Calling A:")
    a.f()
    a.g()
    print("Calling B:")
    b.f()
    b.g()
    print("Calling C:")
    C().g()
```

Output:

```py
Calling A:
Entering wrapper
In class A
Leaving wrapper

g in A
Calling B:
Entering wrapper
In class B
In class A
Leaving wrapper

Entering other wrapper
g in B
g in A
Leaving other wrapper

Calling C:
Entering other wrapper
g in C
g in B
g in A
Leaving other wrapper
```